# Autodesk Forge - Are conversions and post jobs only done once or are they overwritten

Tags: autodesk-forge

Let's say that you want to [extract metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-metadata-from-source-file/) from a file programmatically. At a later date, when the file has changed, I would like to extract the metadata again and get the new data.

If I convert a file on forge to svf a second, third, fourth time, will Forge reconvert the file and send the updated metadata, or is this something that I can set somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [x-ads-force header option](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers) in your translation job to override the derivatives:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer PtnrvrtSRpWwUi3407QhgvqdUVKL' \
     -H 'x-ads-force: true' \
     -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
     -d
'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA"
   },
   "output": {
      "destination": {
       "region": "us"
     },
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "obj",
         "advanced": {
           "modelGuid": "4f981e94-8241-4eaf-b08b-cd337c6b8b1f",
           "objectIds": [
             -2
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/i-make-changes-and-nothing-happens) for more details on issues with updates not taking effect.